# Multi-level interconnected tikz figure

Tags: tikz-arrows

[image: What I'm trying to recreate]

I want to recreate the setup of the figure above. I tried multiple methods and it resulted in a "decent" figure. I am struggling with the connection between sub-figure (circled red in the picture) and to get it properly aligned. Do any of you know how to do this? My creation is:

[image: What I'm trying to recreate]

Using the code

```
   [![\begin{figure*}\[h\]
\textbf{Title1}\par\medskip
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}\[width=7cm,height=4cm,
    xlabel={Temperature \[\textcelsius\]},
    ylabel={Solubility },
    xmin=0, xmax=100,
    ymin=20, ymax=40,
    xtick={0,20,40,60,80,100},
    ytick={20,40},
    legend pos=north west,
    ymajorgrids=true,
    grid style=dashed,
\]

\addplot\[
    color=blue,
    mark=square,
    \]
    coordinates {
    (0,23.1)(10,27.5)(20,32)(30,37.8)(40,44.6)(60,61.8)(80,83.8)(100,114)
    };
    \legend{CuSO\(_4\cdot\)5H\(_2\)O}
    
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{minipage}\[b\]{0.2\textwidth}
\centering
Uses a NLP to minimise Cost using a battery degradation model\\
$\rightarrow$
\end{minipage}%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}\[width=7cm,height=4cm,
    xlabel={Temperature \[\textcelsius\]},
    ylabel={Solubility },
    xmin=0, xmax=100,
    ymin=20, ymax=40,
    xtick={0,20,40,60,80,100},
    ytick={20,40},
    legend pos=north west,
    ymajorgrids=true,
    grid style=dashed,
\]

\addplot\[
    color=blue,
    mark=square,
    \]
    coordinates {
    (0,23.1)(10,27.5)(20,32)(30,37.8)(40,44.6)(60,61.8)(80,83.8)(100,114)
    };
    \legend{CuSO\(_4\cdot\)5H\(_2\)O}
    
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\textbf{Title1}\par\medskip
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}\[width=7cm,height=4cm,
    xlabel={Temperature \[\textcelsius\]},
    ylabel={Solubility },
    xmin=0, xmax=100,
    ymin=20, ymax=40,
    xtick={0,20,40,60,80,100},
    ytick={20,40},
    legend pos=north west,
    ymajorgrids=true,
    grid style=dashed,
\]

\addplot\[
    color=blue,
    mark=square,
    \]
    coordinates {
    (0,23.1)(10,27.5)(20,32)(30,37.8)(40,44.6)(60,61.8)(80,83.8)(100,114)
    };
    \legend{CuSO\(_4\cdot\)5H\(_2\)O}
    
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{minipage}\[b\]{0.2\textwidth}
\centering
Limits export/import capabilities in time frames if voltage violations may occur and sets possible reactive power compensation.\\
$\rightarrow$
\end{minipage}%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}\[width=7cm,height=4cm,
    xlabel={Temperature \[\textcelsius\]},
    ylabel={Solubility },
    xmin=0, xmax=100,
    ymin=20, ymax=40,
    xtick={0,20,40,60,80,100},
    ytick={20,40},
    legend pos=north west,
    ymajorgrids=true,
    grid style=dashed,
\]

\addplot\[
    color=blue,
    mark=square,
    \]
    coordinates {
    (0,23.1)(10,27.5)(20,32)(30,37.8)(40,44.6)(60,61.8)(80,83.8)(100,114)
    };
    \legend{CuSO\(_4\cdot\)5H\(_2\)O}
    
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\textbf{Title1}\par\medskip
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}\[width=7cm,height=4cm,
    xlabel={Temperature \[\textcelsius\]},
    ylabel={Solubility },
    xmin=0, xmax=100,
    ymin=20, ymax=40,
    xtick={0,20,40,60,80,100},
    ytick={20,40},
    legend pos=north west,
    ymajorgrids=true,
    grid style=dashed,
\]

\addplot\[
    color=blue,
    mark=square,
    \]
    coordinates {
    (0,23.1)(10,27.5)(20,32)(30,37.8)(40,44.6)(60,61.8)(80,83.8)(100,114)
    };
    \legend{CuSO\(_4\cdot\)5H\(_2\)O}
    
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{minipage}\[b\]{0.2\textwidth}
\centering

Uses real-time control to prevent voltage violations caused by sudden increase in \gls{pv} generation or change in load demand\\
$\rightarrow$
\end{minipage}%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}\[width=7cm,height=4cm,
    xlabel={Temperature \[\textcelsius\]},
    ylabel={Solubility },
    xmin=0, xmax=100,
    ymin=20, ymax=40,
    xtick={0,20,40,60,80,100},
    ytick={20,40},
    legend pos=north west,
    ymajorgrids=true,
    grid style=dashed,
\]

\addplot\[
    color=blue,
    mark=square,
    \]
    coordinates {
    (0,23.1)(10,27.5)(20,32)(30,37.8)(40,44.6)(60,61.8)(80,83.8)(100,114)
    };
    \legend{CuSO\(_4\cdot\)5H\(_2\)O}
    
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Two Stage Overview with real time control}
    \label{fig:Two Stage Overview}
\end{figure*}
```

Comment: You should have a look to `tikzmark` library. It allows you to make subnodes and remembering them to associate them between figures.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Your code fragment is not compilable due to wrong use of optional arguments in your code. For example wrong  `\begin{figure*}\[ht\]` had to be `\begin{figure*}`[ht]` etc.
- Arrows with text between image can be simply draw as `tizpicture`
- vertical align can be achieved by `\tikzpicture` option `[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]`

Considering aforementioned the first two rows of figure can be:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article} 
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                bending,
                tikzmark}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure*}[ht]
\pgfplotsset{% moved here for shortening of the MWE code
    width=0.35\textwidth,height=4cm,
    xlabel={Temperature [\textcelsius]},
    ylabel={Solubility},
    xmin=0, xmax=100,
    ymin=20, ymax=40,
    xtick={0,20,40,60,80,100},
    ytick={20,40},
    legend style = {font=\footnotesize, legend pos=north west},
    ymajorgrids=true,
    grid style=dashed
            }
\tikzset{lbl/.style = {font=\small,
                       text width=0.2\textwidth,
                       above}
        } 

\textbf{Title 1}\\[1ex]   
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center),
                        remember picture]
\begin{axis}
\addplot +[mark=square]
    coordinates {
    (0,23.1)(10,27.5)(20,32)(30,37.8)(40,44.6)(60,61.8)(80,83.8)(100,114)
    };
\tikzmarknode{A}{\coordinate (A) at (20,22);}
    \legend{\ce{CuSO4\cdot{5}H2O}}
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\hfill
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
\draw[-Straight Barb, semithick]
    (0,0) -- node[lbl]
                {Uses a NLP to minimize Cost using a
                 battery degradation model} (0.22\textwidth,0);\\
    \end{tikzpicture}
\hfill
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
\begin{axis}
\addplot +[mark=square]
    coordinates {
    (0,23.1)(10,27.5)(20,32)(30,37.8)(40,44.6)(60,61.8)(80,83.8)(100,114)
    };
    \legend{\ce{CuSO4\cdot{5}H2O}}
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\textbf{Title 2}\\[1ex]
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center),
                        remember picture]
\begin{axis}
\addplot +[mark=square]
    coordinates {
    (0,23.1)(10,27.5)(20,32)(30,37.8)(40,44.6)(60,61.8)(80,83.8)(100,114)
    };
\tikzmarknode{B}{\coordinate (B) at (35,39);}
    \legend{\ce{CuSO4\cdot{5}H2O}}
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\hfill
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
\draw[-Straight Barb, semithick]
    (0,0) -- node[lbl]
                {Limits export/import capabilities in time frames 
                 if voltage violations may occur and sets possible 
                 reactive power compensation.} (0.22\textwidth,0);\\
    \end{tikzpicture}
\hfill
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
\begin{axis}
\addplot +[mark=square]
    coordinates {
    (0,23.1)(10,27.5)(20,32)(30,37.8)(40,44.6)(60,61.8)(80,83.8)(100,114)
    };
    \legend{\ce{CuSO4\cdot{5}H2O}}
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
%%%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
    \draw[-{Triangle[scale=0.6, bend]}, 
            line width=3mm, gray, semitransparent]
    (A) to[bend right=45] (B);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

[image]